# Why does the output of EXPLAIN change after each SHOW index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, explain

I was trying to improve performance on some queries through indexes using [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) and I noticed each time I used `SHOW index FROM TableB;` the output of the `rows` colums in the `EXPLAIN` of a query changed

Ex:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN Select A.id
     From TableA A
     Inner join TableB B
         On A.address = B.address And A.code = B.code
     Group by A.id
     Having count(distinct B.id) = 1;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                   | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | index  | test_index    | PRIMARY | 518     | NULL                                  | 10561 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 514     | db.B.address,db.B.code                |     1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show index from TableB;
+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| TableB    |          0 | PRIMARY      |            1 | id          | A         |           7 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| TableB    |          0 | PRIMARY      |            2 | address     | A         |          21 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| TableB    |          0 | PRIMARY      |            3 | code        | A         |       10402 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| TableB    |          1 | test_index   |            1 | address     | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| TableB    |          1 | test_index   |            2 | code        | A         |       10402 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| TableB    |          1 | test_index   |            3 | id          | A         |       10402 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

and...

```
mysql> EXPLAIN Select A.id
        From TableA A
        Inner join TableB B
           On A.address = B.address And A.code = B.code Group by A.id
        Having count(distinct B.id) = 1;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                   | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | index  | test_index    | PRIMARY | 518     | NULL                                  | 9800  | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 514     | db.B.address,db.B.code                |     1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: It sounds like you are using a version older than 5.6.6, when "persistent statistics" became available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rows` column should be taken as a rough estimate only. It's not a precise number.

It's based on statistical estimates of how many rows will be examined during a query. The actual number of rows cannot be known until you actually execute the query.

The statistics are based on samples read from the table periodically. These samples are re-read occasionally, for example after you run `ANALYZE TABLE` or certain INFORMATION_SCHEMA queries, or certain `SHOW` statements.

Comment: Does `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` have any effect on this at all?

Comment: No, EXPLAIN EXTENDED just means to add one more column of information to EXPLAIN output, to show the estimated percentage of rows to be filtered by the query. This option is superfluous in MySQL 5.7, because that column is included by default now.

Comment: Great ... Thanks for the response Bill.

Comment: It seems to fluctuate around 20% from what I gathered, isn't that too big of an estimate? For example if I'm working on improving performance, 20% performance increase on a huge query would already be decent imo, but with a margin of error of 20% while testing would throw that completely out of the window.

Comment: Yes, it's true that the estimate is pretty wild. I think that has been a problem for InnoDB for a long time. Example: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36513

Answer (score 0):

I don't find 20% variation in statistics to be a big deal.  In many situations, think of the graph being like an upturned parabola, and you need to know which side of the minimum point you are on.  In complex queries, where the Optimizer is likely to goof, it need a lot more than simple stats, such as Histograms of MariaDB 10.0 / 10.1.  (I don't have enough experience with such to say whether that makes much headway.)

Your particular query is probably going to be performed in only one way, regardless of the statistics.  An example of a complicated query would be a `JOIN` with `WHERE` clauses filtering each table.  The optimizer has to decide which table to start with.  Another case is a single table with a `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` and they cannot both be handled by a single index -- should it use an index to filter, but then have to sort? or should it use an index for `ORDER BY`, but then have to filter on the fly?